# Month Calendar vb.net Multiple Date Selection

Tags: vb.net, date, monthcalendar

my maximum multiple date selection number is 7 so i created 7 textboxes in order to store each date to the accordingly textbox.
i know how to get the start date and the end date . The between dates how i can store them in textboxes ?

Answer (score 0):

MonthCalendar selections are ranges, so you can determine the dates in between the start and end dates using a Do Loop that uses the [AddDays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/system.datetime.adddays.aspx) function.  This is an example that assumes you have 7 TextBoxes with the following naming convention: txtDate1, txtDate2, txtDate3, etc.

```
    'First Date
    txtDate1.Text = MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart.ToShortDateString()

    Dim intCursor As Integer = 1

    'Keep adding days to the starting date until you've reached the end.
    Do Until MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Date.AddDays((intCursor)) >= MonthCalendar1.SelectionEnd.Date

        Dim dteTarget As Date = MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Date.AddDays((intCursor))

        'Casts the Textbox using a naming convention: txtDate1, txtDate2, txtDate3, etc.
        CType(Me.Controls("txtDate" & (intCursor + 1).ToString()), TextBox).Text = dteTarget.ToShortDateString()

        intCursor += 1

    Loop

    'If the end date is not the same as the start date then add that.
    If MonthCalendar1.SelectionEnd.Date <> MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Date Then

        CType(Me.Controls("txtDate" & (intCursor + 1).ToString()), TextBox).Text = MonthCalendar1.SelectionEnd.Date.ToShortDateString()

    End If
```

Comment: This function will be inserted at     Private Sub MonthCalendar1_DateSelected(sender As Object, e As DateRangeEventArgs) Handles MonthCalendar1.DateSelected ? I Tried it and this error occurs Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: That should be a fine place for that code. Do you have the text boxes with the naming conventions of txtDate1 - txtDate7?

Comment: yes the naming of textboxes are txtdate1 txtdate2 e.t.c